# How to add javascript loading (jQuery) for entire Liferay site or portal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, liferay

I want to use `jQuery` on many of my pages, including Web Content portlet. Is it possible to declare javascript files loading on all of the site pages?

I know this can be done in protlet declaration and in theme template.

But is it possible to do this globally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already mention the theme template (e.g. `portal-normal.vm`). In that file you have control over the full HTML skeletton, so it's easy to add the relevant script loader there and it's available on all pages that use the given theme.

That's as global as it gets. Do this to all of the themes you're using (are you using more than one?) and you're set. It's not more than a single line in that file.